# Make an array filterable per hook

Tags: filters, hooks, array

How can I use `do_action` and `add_action` to return an array in `do_action`?

My sample code:

```
function name_fun_one(){
    $namearray[] = array('k1'=> 'text1', 'k2' => 'text1');
    $namearray[] = array('k1'=> 'text2', 'k2' => 'text2');
    do_action('add_in_namearray');
    foreach($namearray as $val)
    {
        //loop 
    }
}

function add_name_fun_one()
{
    $namearray[] = array('k1'=> 'text3', 'k2' => 'text3');
    $namearray[] = array('k1'=> 'text4', 'k2' => 'text4');
}
add_action('name_fun_one', 'add_name_fun_one');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you want to achieve with more words, examples etc. It's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the array filterable, use `apply_filters()` and `add_filter()`. Also, you have to pass the array as an argument to `apply_filters()` and expect it in your callback that is changing that array.

Here is a basic example with slightly more meaningful names:

First we have a function that is running over an array of color names and values in order to print these with a styled example. It offers a hook, so other code (theme, plugins) can change the colors: `apply_filters( 'arr_colors', $colors );`.

```
function print_colors()
{
    $colors = [
        'red'   => '#f00',
        'green' => '#0f0',
        'blue'  => '#00f',
    ];

    $colors = apply_filters( 'arr_colors', $colors );

    foreach ( $colors as $name => $color ) {
        printf(
            '%1$s: <span style="background: %2$s;>&nbsp;</span><br>',
            $name,
            $color
        );
    }
}
```

Now we create a callback function elsewhere that can change the color. Note the check for `isset ( $colors['green'] )`: There may be more than one callback listening on that hook, so `green` could have been removed already before *our* callback is running. Always keep that in mind.

```
/**
 * @param  array $colors
 * @return array
 */
function change_colors( array $colors )
{
    // remove red
    unset( $colors['red'] );

    // soften the green
    if ( isset ( $colors['green'] ) ) {
        $colors['green'] = '#5f5';
    }

    // add fuchsia
    $colors['fuchsia'] = '#f0f';

    return $colors;
}
```

And now we register said callback for the hook in the first function:

```
add_filter( 'arr_colors', 'change_colors' );
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit tough to understand.
I think you want this.

**Define the hook:**

```
function sample_hook() {

    $namearray[] = array('k1'=> 'text1', 'k2' => 'text1');
    $namearray[] = array('k1'=> 'text2', 'k2' => 'text2');

    do_action('sample_hook',$namearray);
    //you can add multiple args in do_action hook like do_action('sample_hook',$arg1,$arg2,$arg2); 

}
```

**Attach your function to the hook using add_action:**

```
add_action('sample_hook', 'sample_function');

function sample_function($namearray) {
    print_r($namearray);
  echo 'Hey, that is amazing.';
}
```

**Don’t forget to add the following line of code to your page, wherever you want the content to be displayed:**

```
sample_hook();
```

If you want to return array this code must be work. Enjoy!!!